# Migrating Google OpenId to new domain

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dotnetopenauth, google-openid

I am using dotnetopenauth to let my users log in via Google. By default, I didn't need any kind of API key or anything, so I just went with that. Now, I need to move the site to a subdomain. I realize now that doing this causes Google to return back a different URL/ID.

How can I tell Google to return the same URLs/IDs regardless of the calling (sub)domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the wildcard operator in the *openid.realm* definition?

For example, if your current domain is mydomain.com and you want to move your site to subdomain.mydomain.com, you could set the *openid.realm* parameter to *.mydomain.com (provided that your new *openid.realm* matches the openid.return_to parameter of the request - see [Google's OpenID dev docs](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID#realm) for more details).

Comment: Yea, I'm using the OAuthWebSecurity library, which sits on top of the dotnetopenauth library. It looks like I'm going to need to override a bunch of code to get this to work. With Facebook, I just logged in and changed the associated domain. This change will be more involved. Thanks for your help.